# Creating grid in QGIS representing trial plots

Tags: qgis, vector-grid

I would like to create a grid in QGIS. This grid shall represent agricultural trial plots (each plot about 4,5 x 10 m). Digitizing each polygon is time-consuming and not very exact.

Is there a simple way to do that?

I tried "create grid" but that always aligns the grid exactly north/south and that is not what I need. I would like to place the grid off that direction.
There was a plugin "breeder map" but it does not seem to be available (QGIS 3.10). Any ideas?

Comment: - just found that rotate and move the grid could be a solution. But maybe there is a more elegant solution especially for trial plots... (e.g. exclude/include the paths inbetween the rows of the trial, which do not have the same size as the plot)